# div tag inside th is not taking full height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working on a html table. In table heading, I want heading name and an image. Table width is fixed and if there are extra columns then it will be scrollable.

Since I want 2 things in heading(text and image), inside the `th` tag of `tr`, I am putting a `div` and making it a `flex` box.

Here is my code:

```
<table class="Table_table__7VuZZ">
   <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <div class="test">
             <div>Layers</div>
             <div>
                <img src="pin.svg" class="icon"/>
             </div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="test">
             <div>Layer Policy Number testing purpose<</div>
             <div>
                <img src="pin.svg" class="icon"/>
             </div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="test">
             <div>Layer Policy Number testing purpose<</div>
             <div>
                <img src="pin.svg" class="icon"/>
             </div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="test">
             <div>Layer Policy Number testing purpose<</div>
             <div>
                <img src="pin.svg" class="icon"/>
             </div>
          </div>
        </th>
    </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td>Primary</td>
       <td>111</td>
       <td>NO</td>
       <td>aa</td>
    </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

And below is the css:

```
.test {
 display : flex;
 height : 100%;
 position : top
}

th, td, tr {
  padding : 0;
  margin : 0
}

table {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  width : 200px;
  overflow: scroll
}

.icon{
  height : 15px;
  width : 15px
}
```

I don't know why `div` inside `th` is not taking 100% height. It is always in centre of the `th`. I try setting height to 100% of div but it is not working. I have set all `padding` and `margin` to 0. Still doesn't works. Here is the codepen link : https://codepen.io/devendra1102/pen/wvEERpx

Does anyone can help to fit the `div` inside `th` to take 100% height?

Comment: I can help you but need further info please. What do you expect from a height 100%: to "stretch" both the text and image? You cannot stretch the text. And if you want it bigger just use `font-size`. I doubt that you want to stretch the image since you set a width and height for the icon. So what do you want exactly please

Comment: I always wants to start the text from the top. Instead, sometimes it starts from centre and sometimes it start top. For image, it is a pin image and I want to always place it at top right

Comment: Also I do not want to set a fixed height or width of heading text. I want to display it completely if it is too long without overflowing or hiding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, to keep the pin image always at the top right, add the following ruleset to your code:

```css
.test {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Then to place the text at the top, add this:

```css
th,
td,
tr {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

### Complete CSS code:

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

th,
td,
tr {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.icon {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
}
```

This will continue to work whatever the width or height of the cells.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is for the content of your cells to be at the top of the cells, add `td,th { vertical-align: top; }`.

If you really want your flex boxes to be the same height as the table cells, then add `td, th { height: 1px; }`

```css
.test {
 display : flex;
 height : 100%;
 background: orange;
 /* position : top this does nothing */
}

th, td, tr {
  padding : 0;
  margin : 0;
}

th, td {
  height: 1px;
}

table {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  width : 200px;
  overflow: scroll
}

.icon{
  height : 15px;
  width : 15px
}
```

```html
<table class="Table_table__7VuZZ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="test">
          <div>Layers</div>
          <div>
            <img
              src="pin.svg"
              class="icon"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="test">
          <div>Layer Policy Number testing purpose</div>
          <div>
            <img src="pin.svg" class="icon" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>

      <th>
        <div class="test">
          <div>Layer Limit</div>
          <div>
            <img src="pin.svg" class="icon" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="test">
          <div>Policy</div>
          <div>
            <img src="pin.svg" class="icon" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Primary</td>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>NO</td>
      <td>aa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Primary</td>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>NO</td>
      <td>aa</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
.test {
 display : flex;
 background: orange;
 /* position : top this does nothing */
}

th, td, tr {
  padding : 0;
  margin : 0;
}

th, td {
  vertical-align: top;
}

table {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  width : 200px;
  overflow: scroll
}

.icon{
  height : 15px;
  width : 15px
}
```

```html
<table class="Table_table__7VuZZ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div class="test">
          <div>Layers</div>
          <div>
            <img
              src="pin.svg"
              class="icon"
              alt=""
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="test">
          <div>Layer Policy Number testing purpose</div>
          <div>
            <img src="pin.svg" class="icon" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>

      <th>
        <div class="test">
          <div>Layer Limit</div>
          <div>
            <img src="pin.svg" class="icon" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
      <th>
        <div class="test">
          <div>Policy</div>
          <div>
            <img src="pin.svg" class="icon" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Primary</td>
      <td>111</td>
      <td>NO</td>
      <td>aa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Primary</td>
      <td>1111</td>
      <td>NO</td>
      <td>aa</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```